# Either prove or disprove the given statement, For all x∈ℝ, there exists y∈ℝ such that (x^2 + y = 1)

Tags: linear-algebra

Can someone please help me understand this question? I'm sort of confused.

> Express the negation of the statement without using the word "not" or the ¬ symbol. Then either prove or disprove the following statement.
>
> $$\forall x\in\mathbb R, \exists y \in \mathbb R \ \text{ such that } \  x^2 + y = 1$$

I'm trying to figure out the negation and I think it's: $$\exists x∈ℝ, \forall y∈ℝ \ \text{ such that } \ x^2 + y = 1$$
Please correct me if I'm wrong.

I have no idea how to start the proof/disproof

Comment: Pick a number $x$, like $17$. Can you find a suitable $y$? Pick $x=-0.3$. Can you find a suitable $y$? Do it for a couple more $x$. The proof will leap out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is true.

$x^2 + y = 1 \iff y = 1 - x^2$. 
Now, for each and every $x$ you input (to the right-hand side), we evaluate the right-hand side, and "spit out" a $y$. So there is indeed some $y$ produced for each and every $x$.

---

FYI:
The correct negation of the statement would read:

$$\lnot\Big(\forall x \exists y\,(x^2 + y = 1)\Big)$$
$$\iff \exists x \, \Big(\lnot \exists y\,(x^2 + y = 1)\Big)$$
$$\iff \exists x \forall y \,\Big(\lnot(x^2 + y = 1)\Big) $$
$$\iff \exists x \forall y\,(x^2 + y \neq 1)$$

Comment: Oh, I understand now!

Comment: Glad to help, Jake!

Comment: Can you explain where I'm trying to go with the proof? Like I understand that you made it so there's a y output for every x input but why should I do that? And where do I need to go from there?

Comment: That shows that for all $x$ (for each and every x input), there exists (some) $y$ (output) such that $x^2 + y = 1$, i.e. such that $y = 1 - x^2$. You're then done. We are NOT trying to prove that there is (some y such that for any x (x^2 + y = 1)...That's a different proposition, and that different proposition is false. The *order* of the quantifiers is crucial.

Comment: Aren't I trying to proof that x^2 + y ≠ 1? Sorry I'm really new to this, there's a lot of things I don't understand.

Comment: NO! We are trying to prove the given statement, not its negation. Since the given statement is true, its negation will necessarily be (and is) false!: $\quad \lnot(\text{true}) \equiv \text{ false}$

Comment: I see! Thanks a lot for clarifying things.

Comment: You're welcome, Jake!

Comment: @amWhy: Nice discourse + 1

Answer (score 0):

Your negation is not correct.  The first stage is there exists $x \in \Bbb R$ such that not (the rest), so the $x^2+y=1$ does not get negated.  It gets negated when you do the next step.

To do the proof, show that if somebody gives you an $x$ you can find a $y$.

Comment: Isn't it supposed to get negated?

Comment: Jake, ultimately, the quantifiers are reversed, so that the negation acts on the quantified expression, i.e., we negate $x^2 + y = 1$, which gives us reversed quantifiers and the quantified expression: $x^2 + y \neq 1$. See how this works, step by step, in my answer. Your negation leaves out the negation of the inner expression $x^2 + y = 1$.